# TypeError: ljust() argument 2 must be char, not unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode, s2

I'm getting the following error when using the s2sphere library in python2.7 at [this location](https://github.com/sidewalklabs/s2sphere/blob/master/s2sphere/sphere.py#L1462).

`ljust() argument 2 must be char, not unicode`

The method is [link to the file on GH](https://github.com/sidewalklabs/s2sphere/blob/master/s2sphere/sphere.py#L1462):

```
    @classmethod
    def from_token(cls, token):
        """Creates a CellId from a hex encoded cell id string, called a token.
        :param str token:
            A hex representation of the cell id. If the input is shorter than
            16 characters, zeros are appended on the right.
        """
        return cls(int(token.ljust(16, '0'), 16))
```

The file appears to be ASCII-encoded so I'm scratching my head over why I am seeing this

Answer (score 0):

The file imports unicode_literals at the top:

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals, division
```

Hence the '0' is a unicode string & the 'token' parameter needs to be unicode to match